# Adding a user's ID behind the <a> tag ref link address

Tags: posts, php, functions, links

Good day, everyone:

I want to make wordpress to add the user's id number behind the ref's link string, so that, for example

```
<div class="toolsbutton"> 
<a href="http://mysite.com/mysite/page-">go this page</a>
 </div>
```

above code will be turning in to a link if the user id is 113 who clicked it, the address will become:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/mysite/page-113">go this page</a>
```

Or, if you know an alternative to do so, please also let me know.

Generally, the purpose will be that a user will be directed to a page that with unified address but there will be a number equal to his id attached behind. every time, someone click the same link, in same page, will have the same effect on each user.
**When a user click it, will be the CURRENT USER, who is a registered user.**

If anyone could tell me if I could create the page at the same time (if not exist), will be terrific!

Thank You

Comment: I resolved it by using a php snippet plugin with Joshc's method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess maybe `wp_get_current_user();` is what your looking for.

Something like this...

```
<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); ?>

<a href="http://mysite.com/mysite/page-<?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>">go this page</a>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user

--

Actually I just re-read the question and maybe your not after the current user? You might want to elaborate the question more so we know the aim better.

Comment: I guess if its the current user then my answer should the trick for the link - not sure how to create a page when the link is clicked tho

Comment: ok, thanks for that, its already good enough :) I am going to try it out and let you know further issue if there is any!

Comment: Hi Joshc, I tried it, but I got Forbidden You don't have permission to access.... message. Do you know the correct method to apply this php code into my link?